# Can't get coordinates using LocationManager

Tags: java, android, coordinates, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing an app that uses the Google Maps V2 API and I'm having trouble do get my coordinates and to put it into the LatLng object... Here's my code:

```
 public class TelaMapa extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity 
                  implements OnMapClickListener, OnCameraChangeListener{

// Google Map
protected GoogleMap googleMap;
private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
protected AndroidLocationSource locationSource;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapa);
}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    configureMap();
}


/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void configureMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        LocationManager LM = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        String bestProvider = LM.getBestProvider(new Criteria(),true);

        Location localAtu;

        /*Location myLocation = LM.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);

        double lat= myLocation.getLatitude();
        double lng = myLocation.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 20));*/


        if(bestProvider != null){
            localAtu = LM.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        } else {
            localAtu = LM.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        }

        LatLng latLng;

        if(localAtu != null){
            latLng = new LatLng(localAtu.getLatitude(), localAtu.getLongitude());

            final CameraPosition position = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                                              .target(latLng)
                                                              .bearing(0)
                                                              .tilt(0)
                                                              .zoom(17)
                                                              .build();

            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position);
            googleMap.moveCamera(update);

            adicionarMarcador(googleMap, latLng);
            locationSource = new AndroidLocationSource();
            googleMap.setLocationSource(locationSource);
            locationSource.setLocation(latLng);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                           "GPS desligado ou indisponível!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                           .show();
        }


        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Desculpe! Não foi possível criar o mapa!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

   }
}
```

That's it, I installed it in my Motorola Atrix and it always show me the toast in the else
block... Thanks for reading!

Comment: you can use http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: Can you both narrow down your code sample to the smallest thing which produces the problem, and specify what problem you're actually seeing?  It's hard to figure out what your actual question is from what you've posted.  Thanks!

Comment: the problem is that the best provider is Null and the localAtu are Null too... So, the toast message is always shown

Comment: Thanks Sanket, i'll try that code in the tutorial, it may work... If doesn't, the problem is my phone

Comment: that code worked for me, thanks Sanket!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by Sanket Kachhela!
Just use this tutorial and it will work fine!
androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial